# Maximize $(z-x)$ such that $x^2 + y^2+ z^2 =1$

Tags: maxima-minima

Here I tried the coordinate geometry, as in the equation represents a sphere. From there $(z-x)$ would imply the distance between the $z$ coordinate and $x$ coordinate so that the difference is maximum.

Since it is a sphere with radius $1$, $z-x =$ distance between $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$; which would be $\sqrt 2$. Could there be any more approaches, calculus approach? (Since three variables are there thought it would be more complicated?)

Comment: It looks like you will always just want $y=0$ to minimize $z-x$ for what it’s worth.

Comment: @NicoTripeny Did you mean "to maximize $z-x$" ?

Comment: You can try Lagrange multiplier method

Comment: Yes I did thank you

Comment: @NicoTripeny That's true logically,though i was looking for a more rigorous way to get to that conclusion.

Comment: Assume otherwise, so $x-z$ is minimized at $(x,y,z)$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Then $x^2+z^2=1-y^2$. So, the point $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-y^2}},0, \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-y^2}})$ is still on the sphere but with a strictly larger difference between the $x$ and $z$ values.

Comment: @NicoTripeny appreciate this,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like a calculus method, this situation is perfect for Lagrange Multipliers. Let $f(x,y,z)=z-x$ and $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$. Since $\{x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n :g(x,y,z) = 1\}$ is a compact set, so by the Extreme Value Theorem, we know it has a maximum. Now, to find the possibilities for the maximum, we solve for $x,y,z,\lambda$ solving $g(x,y,z) = 1$ and
$$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g \implies 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix} = \lambda\begin{pmatrix}
2x,2y,2z
\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus, $\lambda \neq 0$, so we can divide by it to get $y=0$ and
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1/(2\lambda)\\
0\\
1/(2\lambda)
\end{pmatrix}$$
And so solving for $x^2+y^2+z^2= 1$, we get $2\cdot 1/(4\lambda^2) = 1$ which implies $\lambda = \pm1/\sqrt{2}$. This gives the following two possible maxima:
$$(x,y,z) = \left(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \mp \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$$
which give $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{2}$ so the maximum is $\sqrt{2}$ (and the minimum is $-\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: Thanks @Issac ,this was the kind of stuff i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ then (using the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean)
$$ \tag{$*$}
 (z-x)^2 = x^2 - 2xz + z^2 \le 2(x^2+z^2) \le 2
$$
which implies
$$
 -\sqrt 2 \le z-x \le \sqrt 2 \, .
$$
Equality holds in $(*)$ if $y=0$ and $x=-z$, so that the maximum of $z-x$ is attained at $(x, y, z) = (-1/\sqrt 2, 0, 1/\sqrt 2)$ .